# How to provide files for download that might change (but not path) in Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is the controller i have so far created:

```
@Controller
public class DownloadController
{
    @GetMapping(path = "/download")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(
            @RequestParam(value = "file", required = true, defaultValue = "") String param)
    {
        if (!param.equals("win") && !param.equals("linux") && !param.equals("mac"))
        {
            return null;
        }
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + param + ".zip");
        header.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        header.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        header.add("Expires", "0");
        File file = new File("/dl/" + param + ".zip");
        System.out.println("File exists: " + file.isFile() + "path: " + file.getPath()); // <- returns false and path: \dl\{param}.zip
        InputStreamResource isr;
        try
        {
            isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(new File("/dl/" + param + ".zip")));
            return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(header).contentLength(file.length())
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(isr);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Structure:

[image: structure]

I'd like to provide files for download, which are in a folder as shown in structure.

I am doing it this way, because files provided for download might change and I do not want to re-deploy application. However files are not found.

Comment: Ofcourse the files aren't found. You are loading them from `/dl` where they are located in `/MyFolder/dl` so no they aren't found. Instead of an `InputStreamResource` just use a `FileSystemResource` with a path instead of using `File`.

Comment: @M.Deinum so i have to specify absolute path?

Comment: Relative will work but the fact that you start with `/` makes it an absolute path. And relative is from the working dir, which I think is some temp-dir created by the embedded tomcat. So your safest bet is an absolute path.

Comment: @M.Deinum Did not know that `/` makes it an absolute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for fetch resource files from your storage

```
private final Path root = Paths.get("dl");

public Resource load(String filename) {
   try {   
      Path file = root.resolve(filename); 
      Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
      if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {     
          return resource;   
      } else {     
          throw new RuntimeException("Could not read the file!");   
      } 
   } catch ( MalformedURLException e) {   
       throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + e.getMessage()); 
   }
}
```

Also use this code to send file through the rest call. (Implement in the controller)

```
 @GetMapping("/fetch/{filename:.+}") 
 @ResponseBody 
 public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile( @PathVariable String filename ) {     
     Resource file = load( filename );  
     return ResponseEntity.ok()             
      .header( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"" ).body( file ); 
}
```